# JSON and php . . . NOT FOUND

Tags: php, mysql, iphone, json

still a beginner on php i'm trying to get data from my sql table into an iphone app, i decided to use JSON to do so.

To get my data i use :

```
   mysql_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass']);
   //select database
   @mysql_select_db($config['db_name']) or die( "Unable to select database");


   mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

   $fet=mysql_query('select * from  actualites');

   $json = array();

   while($r=mysql_fetch_array($fet)){
    $json[] = $r;
 }

  echo $json_data=json_encode($json);
```

When i print the result into my browser, the json appears but i have a big NOT FOUNT with the following :

```
Not Found

The requested URL /"http:////www.youtube.com//embed//uspc5ZS-YLI/" was not found on this server.
```

And so the JSON file is imcomplete ! I have searched the web but found nothing !

What do i do wrong ?

Thank you very much !

EDIT : I have a well formed JSON until i get the Not found. 
THe value in the db is :

Comment: there's nothing in your php code that could be triggering a redirect to a bad url, so show the code on the OTHER end, e.g. your ios app.

Comment: Looks like you're sending a malformed request to the server, something like: `http://yourserver.com/"http:////www.youtube.com//embed//uspc5ZS-YLI/"`. Start debugging your app.

Comment: What is the value of `$json` after the while loop. Can you add `var_dump($json);` - is the array valid? I can't see where the reference to YouTube comes from.

Comment: I don't believe this has anything to do with JSON or PHP, just a broken link to a video

Comment: where do you make the http request

Comment: sorry but i'm a beginner, do i have to make an echo var_dump($json) ?

Comment: If you're just learning PHP, please **DO NOT** learn the `mysql_query` interface. It's really outdated and being removed from PHP in the future. For low-level database calls [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will make your application much easier to maintain.

Comment: The Json is weel formed and works in the app but it stops at index 34 instead of index 38 !

Comment: Ok i'll learn new PHP in the future thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the result from db looks badly "add_slashes()"-ed somewhere in php code. can you see if that field in db is properly filled? provide sqlfiddle?

EDIT: the code you provided looks normal and should work without problems

Comment: the field in the db is : <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/uspc5ZS-YLI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: try adding http:// as the browser doesnt know if this source is url

if you try to include it it will add it as folder structure to the current url as @Sammitech mentioned

Comment: stack overflow remove the http:// but there is http

Comment: can you provide the code/file in which you try to print it?

Answer (score 0):

Define Content-type for JSON file loaded with PHP.
For JSON:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

For JSON-P:

```
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
```

Comment: no does not change anything thanks

Comment: nope does not change anything